# Sum() Over(ROWS n Preceding) statement not working in python3.7 sqlite3

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to calculate the n day moving some using:

`SELECT sum(Close) OVER (ROWS 10 PRECEDING) AS "10_Day_Sum"` from MGC_Daily

But getting the following error:

```
getNPointAverage
    sumVal = conn.execute('select SUM(Close) Over(ROWS {} PRECEDING) AS "N_Day_Sum" from {} where "Row Num" <= {}'.format(n,contract,day_index)).fetchone()
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

any suggestions why? I have tried changing the statement and when I remove `Over(ROWS {} PRECEDING) AS "N_Day_Sum"` then it runs but as soon as I put it back it breaks again. So the issues lies with the `OVER` statement.

Thanks!

Comment: SQLite supports window functions since version 3.25.0. Probably you use an earlier version. Execute `select sqlite_version();` to check.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something like this. I have version 3.22.00 do you know how I can update sqlite? I tried with pip but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Some notes.  `rows 10 preceding` actually adds the values for *11* rows, not *10*.  You should always be incorporating an `order by` in such logic.  So:

```
select sum(close) over (order by datecol rows 9 preceding) as N_Day_Sum
from MGC_Daily;
```

In older versions of SQLite, you can express this using a correlated subquery:

select (select sum(d2.close)
from (select d2.*
from MGC_Daily d2
where d2.datecol <= d.datecol
order by datecol desc
limit 10
)
) as N_Day_Sum
from MGC_Daily d;